# What is a fan-in of a flip flop?

Tags: fpga, flipflop

What is a fan-in of a flip flop?

It is mentioned in the following context: "...primary inputs that are in the fan-in of each flip flop."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fanout refers to the number of output paths from some system or component. Many flows emanating from something give rise to a picture which looks like a fan.  Fanin is the opposite: the number of inputs converging on some system or component.

Fanout also has a different shade of meaning, referring to the potential maximum number of inputs that can be driven by some output rather than the number actually connected.

These terms are used in other disciplines, such as software. If a function has a large fanout, it means that it calls many other functions.

Comment: Your fan-out definition is wrong. It's the number of inputs that *can* be driven.

Comment: It is undeniable that the word is used this way. Here is an example of this usage in the Wikipedia, which ironically links to the definition which gives the other usage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic#Fundamental_TTL_gate (*"It limits the number of inputs that can be connected (the fanout)."*).

Comment: I think there is a case for both meanings, so I'm going to edit the answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Fan-out** is the number of logical inputs an output **can** drive. (Both Kaz's answer as well as the Wikipedia entry about it are wrong.)
Even for HCMOS fan-out is expressed as the number of *LS-TTL* inputs it can drive. The input current of an HCMOS gate is negligible.

**Fan-in** is a rarely used term simply meaning the number of inputs. 1 input has a fan-in of 1. Silly, but it fits with the fan-out definition.

**edit**
*ravi* says this in his answer (from Wikipedia):

> "Physical logic gates with a large fan-in tend to be slower than those with a small fan-in, because the complexity of the input circuitry increases the input capacitance of the device."

This isn't true. More inputs doesn't necessarily mean a more complex circuit. An 8-input NAND gate has the same input capacitance per pin as a 2-input one. Each input is connected to two MOSFETs, one P-MOSFET and one N-MOSFET.

[image]

If an input has to drive a large number of FETs it will usually be buffered. In a microcontroller an I/O pin will probably only see two FET gates.

**edit** (upon request by *clabacchio*)
To clarify: more complex ICs *may* be slower, but it's *not* because of increased input capacitance as the Wikipedia article claims.
This is the logic diagram of a [74HC30](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT30.pdf):

[image]

Notice that each input only sees one complementary pair. You'll see this in most logic ICs.

Comment: @clabacchio - false false false :-). The 8-input will be slower, but because of the additional stages, not the capacitance, as they claim! The logic diagram, fig. 3 in [this datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT30.pdf) shows explicitly that each input is a complementary pair.

Comment: Right! I missed the last part of the quote :) today I'm not that smart, I should rest a while :) But put a bit more clear that it's not about the input capacitance, while it's indeed slower

Comment: In general I'm rather sceptical about Wikipedia entries. There's always *something* wrong with them :-(

Comment: Unfortunately the term 'fan-out' has been borrowed for use in other disciplines where the Wikipedia definition is used (although strangely, Wikipedia explains it correctly in the [Theory section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanout#DC_fan-out).

Comment: There is no correct or incorrect. Words are not `#define` macros; they have multiple, context-dependent meanings (sometimes confusingly closely related). Fanout is used by people in situations where it doesn't refer to the maximum theoretical driving capacity, so you have to accept that meaning in order to make sense of such a discussion.

Comment: @Kaz - The original meaning was what it can drive. That's still what it means in datasheets and [design guides](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scla007a/scla007a.pdf). It can't mean anything else because there's no schematic. "Words are not #define macros". They should be, especially technical terms invented for a purpose. Otherwise we might as well start calling everything a "thingy".

Answer (score 3):

Within an FPGA or CPLD, it is very common for the data input of a flip flop to be driven by some combinatorial logic.  In many cases, the combinatorial logic and flip flop will be together regarded as a single unit.  The "fan-in" of a flip flop refers to the fan-in of the combinatorial logic which drives it.  For example, a flip flop which is driven by a six-input NOR gate would have a "fan-in" of six.

Answer (score 0):

Fan-in refers to number of inputs in a device e.g. a 3 input AND gate has fan-in of 3. Fain-in  network may also extend to input of input pins.
Physical logic gates with a large fan-in tend to be slower than those with a small fan-in, because the complexity of the input circuitry increases the input capacitance of the device.

Comment: Where did you get that second paragraph? It's wrong.

Comment: I got it from wikipedia   
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_in

Comment: Don't trust Wikipedia blindly! Many lemmas contain errors. The definition of fan-out there is wrong too. It's not trustworthy, and I know several schools which don't allow their pupils to use WP as a source.

Comment: Does same apply for fanout? Is output capacitance also independent of fanout?

Comment: Fan-out isn't about capacitance, but about the current the output can source and sink. The higher this current the faster the output voltage will switch from a logic low to a logic high, and vice versa. The input's capacitances need time to get charged or discharged. But one single input won't see the capacitances of tens of MOSFETs.

Comment: Isn't the only problem w/fan-in the body effect? Not capacitance?